# Reading from Binary file and displaying in listbox

Tags: c#

I'm hoping someone can assist me with this as I'm sitting for hours with no luck. This is the exercise I had to complete.
[Exercise to complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT6Zy.jpg)

I have attempted it, but came across a small issue. When I have to read from the binary file and display in the Listbox as instructed, the data goes next to each other instead of one below the other. This is my code below for the button to create the file and do the calculations:

```
    BinaryWriter bw;
    BinaryReader br;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        //create the file
        bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("mydata", FileMode.Create));

        string val = "";
        string set = "";
        int count = 1;
        double total = 0.0;
        double ave = 0.0;
        string data = "";
        string temp = "";

        string sets = Interaction.InputBox("How many sets would you like to enter ?", "Sets");
        int numSet = int.Parse(sets);

        for (int j = 0; j < numSet; j++)
        {
            val = "";
            set = "";
            data = "";
            ave = 0.0;
            total = 0.0;
            count = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                val = Interaction.InputBox("Enter number " + count + " to store", "Set "+(j+1), "");
                set = set + " " + val;

                total = total + double.Parse(val);
                count++;

            }
            ave = total / 3.0;
            String fave = String.Format("{0:0.00}", ave);
            data = set + " and average: " + fave;
            temp = temp + data + "\n";


        }
        bw.Write(temp);
        bw.Close();

    }
```

The code that follows this is the one that needs to read from the binary file and output in a Listbox.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reading

        br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("mydata", FileMode.Open));
        string output = br.ReadString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(output);
        br.Close();


    }
```

This is what my output currently looks like:

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoeTL.png)

It supposed to be such that the second set of numbers and average goes below the first one.

I hope I was clear enough in expressing my issue and someone can assist me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are reading everything into 1 string, `output`

You only Add 1 Item, `output` to your ListView in your Button2 click method.

You need to Add for each row you want in the ListView.